# How can I group by using just one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm looking for solution to group by just `Store_ID`. I need to find the best employee based on revenue for each store.

I know that in this case I can use `LIMIT(2)`, but I would like to do it in correct way.

[image: Data]

Expected result

[image: Expected to have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (store_id) store_id, full_name, revenue
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY store_id, revenue DESC;
```